# Using VBscript and EnumNetworkDrives, how can I instruct our login script to NOT delete a drive letter mapping and remove the rest upon each login?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I've been working on adding some new parts to an already existing login script using VBscript. I'd like to  use the below code to erase all drive mappings on login.

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set clDrives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives

For i = 0 To clDrives.Count -1 Step 2

    WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive clDrives.Item(i), True, True

Next
```

However, I'd like to add a line to the code which tells it essentially, "if drive letter = Z, do not delete."

Can somebody please assist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: New login script? Y U NO Powershell?

Comment: Powershell script? Y U NO [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902.aspx)?

Comment: We have a bunch of stuff already done in VBscript, not trying to reinvent the wheel. It's not a new script, I'm adding new parts to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might be ok?

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set clDrives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives

For i =  0 To clDrives.Count -1 Step 2

    If clDrives.Item(i) <> "Z:" Then

        WSHNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive clDrives.Item(i), True, True

    End If

Next
```